# Unity Agora APIS Callign issue

Tags: agora.io

How create base64 key and added in this project , or what i pass in header id password in unity Webrequest by which access a restful api of agora , please help me .

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate what RESTful APIs you are trying to use here?  For the client side logic, the SDK should have sufficient set of API methods provided by the agora engine.  If there is something that is only available in the RESTful API, it is probably better to implement on your Server side of the code.

[This documentation](https://docs.agora.io/en/Agora%20Platform/dashboard_restful_communication) contains the information about the RESTful APIs.

Comment: I want when user offline how i found that username not exist , I have channelname , uid of that user whose offline , he is host , when other users enter then checking that room or that user not exist , then auto out . for this region RESTFUL api i guess helpful.

Comment: This sounds like server logic to me.  Your server should be the one keeping track of the online hosts and post those as open rooms list to the client.